# phpstorm problems and issues in laravel method not found, route note found, pdo exception

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

Hi every one i used phpstorm 9 for laravel and was the best but now from four days it first had the error route not found. i update the composer added the dependencies as told on this link
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Laravel+Development+using+PhpStorm

then it worked fine for a day then again  'find' method not found 'string', 'integer' not found.

I installed a new window and the whole thing again it did not worked. then i updated the phpstorm to the newest version updated the plugin etc. but the same problem continues and wasted four days. 
so can some body explain why is that, do the php storm has some issues or what.

the second thing is, is there any good IDE for laravel  like phpstorm which don't have such problems except sublimetext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ijaz Khan did you try to install this package [laravel-ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper)

This will simply solve 90% of your `method not found` about this packages

> This packages generates a file that your IDE can understand, so it can
>   provide accurate autocompletion. Generation is done, based on the
>   files in your project, so they are alway up-to-date more [here](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper/tree/1.11#laravel-ide-helper-generator).